# Pan and Tap gesture recognizer for same view, which need to fail for the other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I need to detect Pan and Tap on the same view, but the tap action is also the first action for pan, so I assume the Tap action need the Pan action to be failed, but then does it make any delay as it has to wait a little bit in order to know if a tap is followed by a movement for a Pan?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the tap action is not the first action for a pan. the tap happens after touch up (e.g. the user lifts their finger). the pan happens while the touch is still down (e.g. the finger is pressing on the screen and starts to move).

try it, it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm worried that if the Pan is too sensitive, so a tap by human finger may not be that precise as a mouse cursor, that a little bit movement is made, then the finger tap will become a pan.

Comment: have you tried it? I have. I think you'll be satisfied. The predefined gesture recognizers are complimentary and can be used together. I've used tap, pan, long press and swipe in the same view.

Answer (score 6):

I know it's old question but if someone got this in search so they can try this

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, 
         shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
   // Don't recognize a pan gesture until a tap fails.
   if gestureRecognizer == self.panGesture && 
          otherGestureRecognizer == self.tapGesture {
      return true
   }
   return false
}
```

So what exactly happening. **We have got request for Pan and need to check if this is Tap or not**. So here it will check and say to `PanGesture` that it should wait before reacting for `TapGesture` to get fail. Same you can do for other overlapping Gestures.

For more info refer [Preferring One Gesture Over Another](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another#overview)

Answer (score 2):

There won't be a conflict unless you do this.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: this is not what @hzxu wants. the gestures will conflict if you do this.

Comment: @XJones, Edited :)