# iOS, Swift 2.3 - UIPanGesture enabled, but UITapGesture disabled on the same UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, swift2

I had one UIView (blue) and I want to detect on it gestures recognizers. I would like to catch Pan and Tap gesture on this view , but when user tap on this view, I want "deliver" this touch/tap to parent view (green).

[image]

My blue UIView:

```
class SwipeView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer!
    var pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

    func setup() {
        tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swipe.onTap))
        tap.delegate = self
        tap.enabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swipe.onPan))
        pan.delegate = self
        pan.enabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

        self.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
    }

    func onTap() {
    }

    func onPan() {
    }

    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Even if I return gestureRecognizerShouldBegin = false green UIView not catch any event. So, how can I do this functionally? Thx for help.

Comment: please see 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307157/pan-and-tap-gesture-recognizer-for-same-view-which-need-to-fail-for-the-other

Comment: @AbuUlHassan, Thx for link, but the main problem is how to "deliver" touch/event to parent view. If I tap on blue view, I would like to receive event in green view, i.e. under blue view is button, so when I tap on blue in position where is button I would receive action button.

Comment: then you should use Bringviewtofront method

Comment: @AbuUlHassan bringSubviewToFront will nothing change, because blue view must catch pan gesture.

Comment: can send me your code  by any mean so i could check whats the problem is.

Comment: Base functionality: http://www21.zippyshare.com/v/FagG4g4a/file.html

Answer (score 0):

Deliver to parent like so:

```
func onTap(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.superview?.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin?(tapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

Comment: You can try and make the superview the new delegate